# Centroid or Center of mass unexpectedly changes on transitioning from 2D curve to the 3D surface of revolution

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, rotation, geometry

I noticed something strange in the calculation of the location of the centroid of a surface of revolution. If you find the centroid of a 2D curve, revolve the curve around its axis, and then find the centroid of the surface of revolution, the axial location of the centroid of the surface is slightly different than the centroid of the curve. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: What is the "its axis" that you are revolving the  curve around?

Comment: To clarify, suppose the function f(x) in the X-Y axis exists, then revolve around the X axis to obtain a figure that is symmetric along y and z, but not x

Comment: In that case the centroid of the curve will not be on the X axis unless $f(x)=0$, while the centroid of the surface always will be by symmetry, so its location may change very non-slightly. You probably mean just the X coordinate of  the centroid. That's because the surface area of conical frustum depends on top and bottom radii and not just on its slant height http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicalFrustum.html So pieces of the curve of equal length contribute equally to its centroid, but when rotated the corresponding pieces of the surface contribute unequally depending on the values of $f(x)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following simple case.
Suppose that you have the line $y=x$ and find the centre of mass of the segment from $x=0$ to $x=10$.   The centre of mass will be at $x=5$.
Now rotate that line about the $x$ axis.
There will be more surface around $x=10$ than around $x=0$ so the centre of mass will move, compared to the 2d case, to a larger value of $x$.

Comment: Well for that example, the CM along the x axis will be 20/3. when you revolve the shape around the x axis, you will end up having a new CM of 7.5 on the x axis. Would this be due to the non linear increase to the weighing factor (in this case mass) when moving from 2D to 3D?

Comment: A point in 2D becomes a line in 3D and not all the lines are the same length.